# Why does twitter bootstrap exceed my spans when in a form-horizontal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm experimentating with laying out a form using Twitter Bootsrap (i.e. 12 column grid).

I have a two column layout - 2/3 - 1/3 so I have a 2 divs with span8 and span4 as their respective classes.

This works fine, but when I do the same thing inside a form with the form-horizontal class, the labels seem to be wider and push the textboxes across into the gutter.

How can I fix this?

Here's a demo in jsfiddle. The top part works fine, the second form is the strange one.

```
<div class="container">
<form class="">
    <div>This form is fine!</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
      <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="span8" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Age</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="span4" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div>This form is broken!</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span8">Span 8</div>
      <div class="span4">Span 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="span6" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Age</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="span2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Here's [My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdshearer/8Xf2j/11/)

Comment: try assigning a span12 to your form class.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem unforunately.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the css, it looks like they didn't calculate out the width of the form fields correctly in the situations you had. You can either make the label width smaller (which is what I did) or make the input field smaller.

If you add this css it should fix your problem:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    width: 100px;
}
.form-horizontal .controls{
    margin-left: 120px;
}

/* if you are using responsive bootstrap */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .form-horizontal .controls {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/LutqC/1/